# I want to multiply a volume integral by a constant vector, is it possible to include the vector in the integral?

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

I want to multiply a volume integral by a constant vector $\vec v$, is it possible to include the vector in the integral?
$$
\Bigl( 
\int \limits\int \limits\int \limits \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} dxdydz \Bigr) \cdot \vec v\overset{?}{=}
\int \limits\int \limits\int \limits \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}\cdot(\vec {v}) dxdydz
$$

Comment: Hint: the integral on the right is a vector. Therefore the right hand side is a linear expression of three integrals. What is the right hand side ?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm a little confused by the wording. I thought $\int \limits\int \limits\int \limits \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} dxdydz $ is a scalar, multiplied by $\vec v$ the left side becomes a vector.  The right side of the equation ist the triple integral of the scalar $\begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}\cdot(\vec {v})$, so I would think that the right side is a scalar. Summary: The left side is a vector and the right side is a scalar. But I'm not sure if I misunderstood something, because in a solution to an exersice the equality holds.

Comment: Oh no, $\int \limits\int \limits\int \limits \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} dxdydz$ is a vector, right? Then both sides are scalars

Comment: Yes. And can you pull in/out the constant vector $\vec v$ ?

Comment: Yes, I end up multiplying the individual integrals by a constant, integrals are linear maps so I can pull the constants before the integral i.e. the vector $\vec v$.
That's probably what you meant by linear expression.

Comment: Correct. $\phantom{x}$

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved in the comments.